# Can I run radio programs like Motorola CPS for programming radios? If so, How do I load it?

Tags: programming

I use dos based and windows based radio programming software to program motorla and kenwood radios.   I use this for Public Service and Amateur use. Can I get Ubuntu to do this?

Comment: The first entry in the Synaptic Package Manager is Amateur Radio.   So There may be a suitable program in that list.  If not already loaded, Synaptic can be downloaded from the Ubuntu Software Center.  Also have you explored eham.net? There may be something informative there.  http://www.eham.net/

Comment: I know that this is old, but please do not criticize me. I do not believe that there is an official way of doing it, because of how proprietary Motorola (specifically, not entirely sure about Kenwood) is. More than likely, the software is only supported on Windows. I have attempted to run the software through WINE, only to realize that the drivers cannot be run because they are not compatible with Linux. Unless you think that you can port the drivers to the Linux kernel, this cannot be done.